# Failed to set break point at startup with Lauterbach for Multicore controller

Tags: microcontroller, multicore, trace32, lauterbach

I'm using Lauterbach debugger to connect Tricore controller(SPC58NG84,Configured CORE0 as Master,CORE1-Not used,CORE2-Slave).

I followed below sequence to set break point.

Target Reset-->Set breakpoint in software function at Core 2 -->Run Lauterbach

After running software Lauterbach fails to hit breakpoint even the function in CORE2 executes.

If I set Break point first in function which runs in CORE1 then set Break point in the function which runs in CORE2 it works.

I see the same issue in my previous projects also If we set breakpoint CORE2 after target reset it fails.

Can you please help me how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you are debugging a TriCore? Because SPC58NG84 is an automotive PowerPC...

Comment: Hi Holger thanks for responding yes the controller is automotive power pc controller and  it is tricore controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try again with

```
SYStem.Option.CoreStandBy ON
```

This helps to set breakpoints on cores that are in reset at the time the breakpoint is set.